# Passing the value from curElement to another private sub

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have a For Each inside a Private sub and I want to pass the value of the cuElement to another Private sub.

```
Dim theAnchorsCollection As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
theAnchorsCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theAnchorsCollection
            curElement.Style = "style code here"
            AddHandler curElement.Click, AddressOf OnaClick
Next
```

And I want to pass the value to this other sub:

```
 Private Sub OnaClick(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    Dim endereco As String
    endereco = curElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString()
    'Do other things
End Sub
```

I want to know if in this sub I can use something to get the value of the other's curElement.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I got your question right: You want to use a variable `myVariable` of a private sub `mySub1` in another private sub `mySub2`!? You could do this by setting `myVariable` as `public shared`. This way the value of the variable can be used in every sub of the project, because it is a global variable then.

Comment: That's what I did, but that way I have to repeat a lot of code in order to get the href of each <a>, because since it is inside the For Each Cycle, if I do for example myVar = curElement, it will allways apply the last <a>

Comment: Nvm I found what I wanted, it was sender the variable that I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer it was (sender) the variable that I wanted.

As I found in the MSDN Forums

As you use Addhandler to subscribe for a given event, you pass required arguments of event to the procedure with AddressOf that delegates , whose argument signature "must" be same as event's.

A demo:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Button1.MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
    End Sub

    Sub btn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        MsgBox(e.Button.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Using Addhandler, we're subscribing MouseDown event of button, and specifiying the procedure which gonna be called on the follow. The passed arguments are object(sender) and MouseEventArgs (e), and you can use this in your event sub like above. (eg: To get mousebutton that was down.)